# wrap a bunch of functions within document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is probably more a matter of syntax than anything else. I have some simple code that controls some custom tabs that flow on and off screen when clicked. For the most part the code (especially animation) works as intended and is not problematic.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.side_drawer_face').click(function() {

                            if ($('#side_drawer').css("left") <= "0"){
                                  $('#overlay_div').show();  
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 5000;
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '+=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '+=406'}, 500);

                            } else if ($('#side_drawer').css("z-index") == "6000"){
                                  $('#overlay_div').hide();
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 5000;
                            }   else {
                                      document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                      document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 5000;

                                }

                        });
                    $('.side_drawer_face2').click(function() {
                                //shows Bio div
                            if ($('#side_drawer2').css("left") <= "0"){
                                  $('#overlay_div').show(); 
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 5000;
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '+=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '+=406'}, 500);
                            } else if ($('#side_drawer2').css("z-index") == "6000"){
                                  $('#overlay_div').hide();
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);

                            } else {
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 5000;

                            }
                        });
                    $('.clear_overlay').click(function() {

                                  $('#overlay_div').hide();
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 5000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 6000;
                        }); 

                    </script>
```

My problem is, in some browsers (that begin with I and end in E) rapidly clicking on the tab while other page elements are loading cause unexpected behavior. What I'd like to do is wrap the entire script with a document ready statement so that none of the functions can be executed until everything on the page is loaded. (the script is already located at the bottom of the html body)

Comment: so.... why don't you wrap the functions in the document.ready event? I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: In theory this code inside the script tag should already be contained in a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` as its using jQuery. Also, why are you using a combination of jQuery selectors and `document.getElementById`? Seems odd.

Comment: because symantically I'm not sure if it's as easy as $(document).ready(function(){
   my functions...
})

Comment: Why not just try and find out? I suspect it will fix your problems.

Comment: You're right, I should have tried it first. For some reason I thought it would be more involved than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                     $('.side_drawer_face').click(function() {

                            if ($('#side_drawer').css("left") <= "0"){
                                  $('#overlay_div').show();  
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 5000;
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '+=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '+=406'}, 500);

                            } else if ($('#side_drawer').css("z-index") == "6000"){
                                  $('#overlay_div').hide();
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 5000;
                            }   else {
                                      document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                      document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 5000;

                                }

                        });
                    $('.side_drawer_face2').click(function() {
                                //shows Bio div
                            if ($('#side_drawer2').css("left") <= "0"){
                                  $('#overlay_div').show(); 
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 5000;
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '+=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '+=406'}, 500);
                            } else if ($('#side_drawer2').css("z-index") == "6000"){
                                  $('#overlay_div').hide();
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);

                            } else {
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 6000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 5000;

                            }
                        });
                    $('.clear_overlay').click(function() {

                                  $('#overlay_div').hide();
                                  $('#side_drawer').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  $('#side_drawer2').animate({ opacity: 1.0, left: '-=406'}, 500);
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer2').style.zIndex = 5000;
                                  document.getElementById('side_drawer').style.zIndex = 6000;
                        }); 

});
```

Comments by Nick and Matt are correct -- the syntax is super-easy, just bind the event handlers in the `ready` function